# How to dynamically create a number of fields based on the number in another number input?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I want this behaviour and below are code snippets:

When field X changes its numeric (integer) value (through user interaction):

1. if X's value is bigger now, add new fields to the field array (called A) until there are X fields (the fields in the array should be either `number`-typed or `<select>`s)
2. else if X's value is lower now, remove the last fields in the field array A until there are only X fields

This is my starting point:

```
const { fields, append, prepend, remove, swap, move, insert } = useFieldArray(
  {
    control,
    name: "A",
  }
);

watch((data, options) => {
  // console.log('d, o', data, options);

  if (options.name === 'X') {
    let z = data.X;
    while (z) {
      // remove?
      --z;
    }
  }
});
```

In the docs it is said to not put multiple remove calls in a single render and I also wish to keep existing values if the input does not change its value in a way that would affect existing values (so the values in A should be kept).

I also use this, but it is another part of the component that should be fine:

```
{X > 0 && (
    <div>
        {fields.map((field, index) => {
...
```

I could do this in pure React but I am using the react-hook-form module and I am wandering how can I do this wanted behaviour without abandoning the react-hook-form dependency.

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [the Controller component](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) in the same package, react-hook-form.

```
if (f.type === "multiple") {
  return (
    f.condition() && (
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={f.name}
        defaultValue={[]}
        render={({
          field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
          fieldState: { invalid, isTouched, isDirty, error },
          formState,
        }) => {
          let seq = [];
          const x = f.count();
          for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            seq.push(i);
          }

          return (
            <div tabIndex={0} onBlur={onBlur} ref={ref}>
              {seq.map((field, index) => {
                return (
                  <React.Fragment key={index}>
                    {f.renderChild({ index, onChange })}
                  </React.Fragment>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      />
    )
  );
}
```